# Why did Ashkenazi Jews not adopt the custom of reading the Book of Job in synagogue on Tisha B'Av, as Sephardim do?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, tisha-bav, job-iyov-book-of

I understand that Sephardim have the custom of reading the Book of Job on Tisha B'Av.  Is there any historic discussion among Ashkenazi rabbis regarding why the practice was not adopted by them?

Comment: Maybe for the same reason they don't read the book of Tzefanya either.

Comment: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppHkB.png) See Machzor Polin for the contrary https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PS9fAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT213&lpg=PT213&dq=%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8+%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA+%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8+%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97&source=bl&ots=9Ys2sFnzv-&sig=MOv50MbWDcHoHdfzLv27DeRNJNE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfnuTmlvjPAhVhDsAKHVVPAwoQ6AEIMzAF#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: why would they?